# Shuffling an Adapter

Tags: android, shuffle, android-adapter

I am using an `Adapter`:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
```

and I want to shuffle the contents of it, however I discovered that `Collections.shuffle(adapter);` does not work. Is there another method to do this? While keeping the format of `adapter` i.e. not changing it to a `List`

Comment: are you calling notifydatasetchanged() after shuffling on your adapter ?

Comment: If you don't want to use a List you may have to write a shuffle method yourself.  [Random shuffling of an array in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array-in-android)

Comment: @AalokSharma adapter is not a supported type for `Collections.shuffle()`

Comment: okay @rsayles3 My comment meant that are u calling notifydatasetchanged() on your adapter after calling shuffle ... is it understandable now , and have you even read the title of your question "Shuffling an Adapter" ??

Answer (score 2):

Of course `Collections.shuffle(adapter)` doesn't work..shuffle takes a java.util.List... The Java Collections API knows nothing about the Android API...

You need to shuffle the underlying List and then then tell the adapter that the data has changed..something like:

```
Collections.shuffle(myList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Does this work with a primitive array as specified?

Comment: I don't have an underlying list, the adapter is populated manually by a user entering in String via a text input and that adapter is set in a `ListView`

Comment: @rsayles3 Then you should collect the user input in a collection and base your adapter on that.  The adapter should only be the V in the MVC pattern.